# Microsoft Knowledge API - Searching for a sentence in the database

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to integrate the new Microsoft Knowledge API to my app. I need to search in the database to find results similar to a google/bing search.

So far I've made this request - and its working well:

https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=And(W=%27bandwidth%27)&attributes=Id,Ti,Y,D,CC,E&subscription-key=MY-API-KEY

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/paperentityattributes) W argument is searching only in the title and the abstract, I need to search at the whole paper.

How can i query a sentence from the database?

Answer (score 3):

I work on Academic Knowledge API!

The major role of Academic Knowledge API is to enable semantic search over knowledge graph. For keyword search experience, we are leveraging the full power of Bing Custom Search, a separate service in Microsoft Cognitive Services. You can see how the two APIs can be combined at our [Microsoft Academic website](https://preview.academic.microsoft.com) using the query like "how to jump higher playing basketball"

We're considering offering Bing Custom Search + Academic Graph as an additional outlet to our Academic Knowledge API!

Comment: Can I right now use a custom search with the Bing API to query the Academic Knowledge database? Do you have an example of how to do that? Or doing so combining the Academic Knowledge Graph?

Comment: Are there any advancement over the last couple of months in the service that you can share with us?